# Using types from external library in IDL file

Tags: types, nuget, windows-runtime, external, idl

I want to create an IDL file for my COM server and one of the methods use a type that is not a Windows Runtime type. How can I import that namespace that comes from a NuGet repository?

My IDL file looks like as follows:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    runtimeclass Main
    {
        Main();
    }
    
    void MenuClick(Repository repository, String location, String menuName, String itemName);
}
```

The concerning type is 'Repository' which comes from a NuGet. Is it possible to do it?

Currently I get the following error when I run syntax check on the IDL file:
error MIDL2011 : [msg]unresolved type declaration [context]: Repository [ Parameter 'repository' of Procedure 'MenuClick'  ]

Comment: If the type is not a Windows Runtime type, then there is no way to express it in the Wndows Runtime. You'll have to create a Windows Runtime version of that type, or treat it as an untyped parameter (Object).